# Looping with XML data in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XSLT that is supposed to loop to a series of data but seems I have an error when I tried to run it in VS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="vZeroInt" select ="'0'" />
  <xsl:variable name="vZeroDbl" select ="'0.00'" />

  <xsl:template match="/Document">
    <Values>
      <xsl:call-template name="PTags">
        <xsl:with-param name="Data" select="PValues" />
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:call-template name="XTags">
        <xsl:with-param name="Data" select="XValues" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </Values>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="PTags">
    <xsl:param name="index" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="total" select="10" />
    <xsl:param name="Data" />

    <xsl:variable name="num" select="concat('P_',format-number($index,'00'))" />
    <xsl:call-template name="DisplayNumericTag">
      <xsl:with-param name="IsMandatory" select="1" />
      <xsl:with-param name="IntValue" select="1" />
      <xsl:with-param name="TagName" select="$Data/{$num}" />
      <xsl:with-param name="TagValue" select="$Data/{$num}" />
    </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:if test="not($index = $total)">
      <xsl:call-template name="PTags">
        <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="XTags">
      <xsl:param name="index" select="1" />
      <xsl:param name="total" select="10" />
      <xsl:param name="Data" />

      <xsl:variable name="num" select="concat('X_',format-number($index,'00'))" />
      <xsl:call-template name="DisplayNumericTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="IsMandatory" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="IntValue" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagName" select="$Data/{$num}" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagValue" select="$Data/{$num}" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:if test="not($index = $total)">
        <xsl:call-template name="XTags">
          <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="DisplayNumericTag">
      <xsl:param name = "IsMandatory" />
      <xsl:param name = "IntValue" />
      <xsl:param name = "TagName" />
      <xsl:param name = "TagValue" />

      <!--Display the tag only if its manadatory and value is non zero-->
      <xsl:if test="$IsMandatory=1 or $TagValue!=0">
        <xsl:element name="{$TagName}">
          <xsl:choose>
            <!--Integer Numbers-->
            <xsl:when test="$IntValue='1'">
              <xsl:value-of select="format-number(concat($TagValue, substring($vZeroInt, 1 div not(string($TagValue)))),'0')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <!--Double type numbers-->
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="format-number(concat($TagValue, substring($vZeroDbl, 1 div not(string($TagValue)))),'#0.00')"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And using this XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document>
  <PValues>
    <P_01>100</P_01>
    <P_02>200</P_02>
    <P_03>300</P_03>
    <P_04>400</P_04>
    <P_05>500</P_05>
    <P_06>600</P_06>
    <P_07>700</P_07>
    <P_08>800</P_08>
    <P_09>900</P_09>
    <P_10>1000</P_10>
  </PValues>
  <XValues>
    <X_01>0</X_01>
    <X_02>200</X_02>
    <X_03>300</X_03>
    <X_04>400</X_04>
    <X_05>0</X_05>
    <X_06>600</X_06>
    <X_07>700</X_07>
    <X_08>800</X_08>
    <X_09>900</X_09>
    <X_10>1000</X_10>
  </XValues>
</Document>
```

Im trying to convert it into something like this:

```
<Document>
  <Values>
    <P_01>100</P_01>
    <P_02>200</P_02>
    <P_03>300</P_03>
    <P_04>400</P_04>
    <P_05>500</P_05>
    <P_06>600</P_06>
    <P_07>700</P_07>
    <P_08>800</P_08>
    <P_09>900</P_09>
    <P_10>1000</P_10>
    <X_01>0</X_01>
    <X_02>200</X_02>
    <X_03>300</X_03>
    <X_04>400</X_04>
    <X_05>0</X_05>
    <X_06>600</X_06>
    <X_07>700</X_07>
    <X_08>800</X_08>
    <X_09>900</X_09>
    <X_10>1000</X_10>
  </Values>
</Document>
```

But I have an error when I pass on the data with this `"$Data/$num"`.
Can anyone show me or help me to correct this error.

Currently, Im doing it like this thats is why I wanted to loop:

```
      <xsl:call-template name="DisplayNumericTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="IsMandatory" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="IntValue" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagName" select="'P_01'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagValue" select="P_01" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="DisplayNumericTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="IsMandatory" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="IntValue" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagName" select="'P_02'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagValue" select="P_02" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="DisplayNumericTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="IsMandatory" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="IntValue" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagName" select="'P_03'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagValue" select="P_03" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="DisplayNumericTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="IsMandatory" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="IntValue" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagName" select="'P_04'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagValue" select="P_04" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="DisplayNumericTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="IsMandatory" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="IntValue" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagName" select="'P_05'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagValue" select="P_05" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="DisplayNumericTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="IsMandatory" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="IntValue" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagName" select="'P_06'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagValue" select="P_06" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="DisplayNumericTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="IsMandatory" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="IntValue" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagName" select="'P_07'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagValue" select="P_07" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="DisplayNumericTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="IsMandatory" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="IntValue" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagName" select="'P_08'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagValue" select="P_08" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="DisplayNumericTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="IsMandatory" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="IntValue" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagName" select="'P_09'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagValue" select="P_09" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      <xsl:call-template name="DisplayNumericTag">
        <xsl:with-param name="IsMandatory" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="IntValue" select="1" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagName" select="'P_10'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="TagValue" select="P_10" />
      </xsl:call-template>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't look as if your `$Data` param is ever set. If you want to select nodes with the `$num` value, you would probably use it differently (maybe in a predicate selecting where the position is equal to that number: `[position()=$num]`. This whole XSLT looks to be more complicated than it needs to be. If you are simply renaming elements and eliminating the `XValues` and `PValues` elements, there is an easier and more succinct way to do that.

Comment: Sorry, i have edited the stylesheet, the XSLT is actually a part of a much bigger one and I need the template as it is because it has some conditions on it whether it is an integer number or a double and whether it needs to show (mandatory) or not

Comment: `$Data/{$num}` is not a valid XPath expression. It's hard to tell what the correct expression should be because we don't know what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: what im doing is to loop the P tags in "PTags" then while looping the DisplayNumericTag will identify if the tag and value pair should be displayed or not depending on the params, so the Data is getting passed on those two templates from main

Comment: I am afraid that makes no sense to me. You are explaining *how* you do it, instead of *what* you are trying to accomplish by doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet seems overly complex. If you are just looking to consolidate the content of `PValues` and `XValues` under a `Values` element, then you could do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Document">
        <xsl:copy>
          <Values>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*/*"/>
          </Values>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```